# Why after the first ARP ping scan to my local network with scapy I don't have internet connection?

Tags: python-3.x, ping, scapy, arp

Does anyone have any idea why after the first ARP ping scan to my local network (wlan0 interface) it's not possible to perform the same scan again?

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="192.168.1.0/24"), iface=wlan0, timeout=2)
Begin emission:
Finished sending 256 packets.
*****......
Received 11 packets, got 5 answers, remaining 251 packets
>>> ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%Ether.src% %ARP.psrc%") )
28:2e:a4:7f:d0:b6 192.168.1.1
cc:ff:a4:2a:5b:46 192.168.1.2
ce:ae:13:e6:7c:73 192.168.1.7
e0:56:cb:8f:5f:60 192.168.1.11
a0:d3:3a:3f:fa:1e 192.168.1.20
```

After the first scan I don't have connectivity to hosts in the network even to internet. This doesn't happen when performing an ARP ping scan to virtual interfaces.

```
>>> ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="192.168.1.0/24"), iface=wlan0, timeout=2)
Begin emission:
```

Does anyone have any idea why this behavior?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Does `arp -a` show a different MAC for `192.168.1.1` (I'm assuming that's your default gateway)?

Comment: Yes `192.168.1.1` is the default gateway, the arp table appears to be reseted, I don't understand that behavior when using scapy, when I use arp-scan or another tool that doesn't happen.